# GoのEchoでテンプレートから別パッケージの構造体を参照

Tags: go

GoのライブラリEchoを使用して、まずは下記参考サイトと全く同じソースを作成し、動作することを確認しました。
その後、下記参考サイトの「ServiceInfo」構造体を別のパッケージ(ここでは例でtestパッケージとします)に分割したところ、Internal Server Errorとなってしまいました。

テンプレートから別パッケージの構造体を参照するにはどのように指定することとなるのでしょうか。

参考サイト
http://kimagureneet.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/01/12/210553

Go バージョン1.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
package test

type ServiceInfo struct {
    Title string
}
```

↑ のように test パッケージに serviceinfo.go を追加し、
↓ のように service.go で import して test package を指定すれば問題なさそうでした。

```
import (
   ・・・

    "github.com/hoge/test"

   ・・・
)

・・・

var serviceInfo = test.ServiceInfo{
    "サイトのタイトル",
}
```